# sqlite3 python3 deleting cascade does not work as expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I have created these tables:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('scheduler1111111.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('pragma foreign_keys = ON;')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE sections
                    (id_sect INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)''')

c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS subjects''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE subjects
                    (id_subj INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, career TEXT)''')


c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS professors''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE professors
                    (id_p INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, lastname TEXT, cedula TEXT)''')

c.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS scheduler''')
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE scheduler
                    (id_sch INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, id_sect INTEGER, id_subj INTEGER, id_p INTEGER, Day TEXT, From_time INTEGER, To_time INTEGER,
                    FOREIGN KEY (id_sect) REFERENCES sections (id_sect)
                     FOREIGN KEY (id_subj) REFERENCES subjects (id_subj),
                     FOREIGN KEY (id_p) REFERENCES professors (id_p) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT)''')
```

Suppose i have professors Mike X and John Z in the professors tables, and i already have sections in the sections table, and the same on the subjects tables, if i try to add a professor on the scheduler table that is not in the professor table it won't allow me, so it works as i expected it too, however, if i fill a few rows in the scheduler, and input say, the same professor, Mike X in three of the rows, then i go and delete the professor Mike X from the professors table, i thought these three rows on the scheduelr table with Mike X in it would be deleted as well, but what i get is  *NULL* in the column id_p, how can i make it so it actually deletes all of the rows so that delete cascade works as expected and not just NULLS the fields on the child table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but what i get is NULL in the column id_p

Well, yes, because you told SQLite to do that:

```
FOREIGN KEY (id_p) REFERENCES professors (id_p) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT
```

The `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` part means "when the row referenced by `id_p` is deleted, set the `id_p` column to its default value", which for a `NOT NULL` column is `NULL` unless otherwise specified.

Change `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`.